# Amazon Connect time out with Lex Bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have an Amazon Connect Contact Flow setup which is working correctly apart from the last step.

The 'Get Customer Input' block points to my Lex bot which uses Lambda to read an S3 file and say the contents back to the user.  The user must first confirm a couple of slots which work - the final step is the fulfilment stage where the lambda script is called to read the file and pass the contents back to Lex (It does this by passing the Close Dialog Action with the message as the contents of the s3 file).

Lex begins to read the contents but get's cut off half way through as I believe the 'Get Customer Input' block thinks the Lex bot has finished and moves on to the next block in the flow.  Is there some kind of timeout option I'm missing (I've extended both the lambda and the lex timeouts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried extending the DTMF timeout period and this did solve this issue at the end of the call - but in doing so extended the timeouts for the simple questions at the start of the call and left long blank pauses.

In the end I moved my code which grabbed the long sentences from the 'FullfilmentCodeHook' and placed it in the 'DialogCodeHook' section as a 'Confirm Intent' dialogAction.

This means the message plays all the way through and expects a confirmation from the user - but if the user doesn't confirm anything then it just carries on to the next block which is what I'm after :)

Comment: One quick question, How did you resolve this? I am facing the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977353/timeout-issue-in-amazon-connect